# curl command line and twitter

Tags: curl, twitter

I'm calling the twitter search using the command line and for all things it
works well , except for searches beyond the first page.

```
curl --silent --include -k https://mobile.twitter.com/search?q=michael
```

works fine, and I find the 'load older' results link after I parse, and 
come up with

```
curl --silent --include -k https://mobile.twitter.com/search?max_id=273642014212501504&q=michael
```

calling this , only returns the signup page, and no search results -

however, if i paste the url with the max_id into a browser, the results come up 
correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Twitter has a [search API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search). You should use it.

```
curl -si http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=michael
```

and

```
curl -si http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=michael&max_id=273642014212501504
```

both works fine and returns easily parsable json which should serve your needs.

Replace `search.json` with `search.atom` if you prefer results in [atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29).

Comment: @AshodApakian Then why aren't you using it?

Comment: Because I'm attempting to write a search engine, and developing a web crawler

Comment: @AshodApakian And you're doing it in bash? You should take a look at https://mobile.twitter.com/robots.txt. Twitter doesn't really want you to crawl that page, and you should respect that.